# unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

```
JACOB=192.168.1.66
ZAC=192.168.1.65
echo "Type someone's name, or type ? to list options."
read OPTNAME
if [ $OPTNAME = "?" ]; then
        echo "Jacob's Computer: Type 'JACOB'"
        echo "Zac's Computer:   Type 'Zac'"
        echo "Help:             Type 'Help'"
else
        if [ $OPTNAME = "JACOB" ]; then
                echo "Jacobs Computer chosen."
                echo "Now, enter the directory of the file you want to put onto this computer."
                read FILEPATH
                echo "Okay, would you like to specify a directory on the other computer, in which to place the file? (y/n)"
                read YN
                echo "DEBUG $YN"
                if [ $YN = "y" ]; then
                        echo "Okay, in which directory would you like to put the file?"
                        read FILETO
                        echo "Are you ready to send the file? y/n"
                        echo "Reciever name: $OPTNAME"
                        echo "File to send: $FILEPATH"
                        echo "Where to put the file: $FILETO"
                elif [ $YN = "n" ]; then
                        echo "Are you ready to send the file? y/n"
                        echo "Reciever name: $OPTNAME
                        echo "File to send: $FILEPATH"
                        echo "Where to put the file: N/A"
                fi
        elif [ $OPTNAME = "ZAC" ]; then
                echo "Zacs Computer chosen."
        fi
fi
```

This is a code I'm writing to be able to specify a file and user to send a file to their computer. I'm having a problem where when I run it, it returns these errors:

```
filetransfer.sh: line 32: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
filetransfer.sh: line 35: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: Add a `"` at line 26.

Comment: You have a missing quotes on this line - `echo "Reciever name: $OPTNAME"` . Just add that quote and you should be fine..

Comment: If you look closely, you'll see that Super User nearly answered the question for you.  Up through line 26, the strings are brown and the commands are black and blue.  After line 26, the commands are brown and the strings are black and blue.  That's a sign that our parser thinks that the commands are strings (and vice versa), because of an unmatched quote.  (By the way, since "Receiver" contains a "c", it is spelled with the "i" *after* the "e".)